# Haskell Graphing Module (Gloss)

Tags: beginner, haskell, data-visualization

I've been slowly learning Haskell over the past few months. I made a small module to graph functions using Gloss, and I would like feedback on how idiomatic it is (looking for ways to simplify using standard functions and to make it more pointfree).

Graph.hs

```hs
module Graph (graph) where

import Graphics.Gloss

graph :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) dx = pictures $ map Line visible
    where
        points :: [(Float, Float)]
        points = [(x, f x) | x <- [l,l+dx..r]]

        pairs :: [[(Float, Float)]]
        pairs = zipWith (\x y -> [x,y]) points $ tail points

        visible :: [[(Float, Float)]]
        visible = filter (all (\(_,y) -> b <= y && t >= y)) $ pairs
```

Main.hs

```hs
import Graphics.Gloss

import Graph

main :: IO ()
main = display FullScreen white . scale 20 20 . pictures $ [
        color blue $ graph f (-10, 10, -10, 10) 0.001,
        color black $ Line [(0, -10), (0, 10)],
        color black $ Line [(-10, 0), (10, 0)]
    ]
    where
        f :: Float -> Float
        f x = 1 / (x - 1)
```

Output
[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks great. Honestly, there isn't anything I'd change. You could make it more pointfree in some parts, but that's not going be more readable or maintainable.

## Magic numbers

The only part I'd change are the static dimensions in `main`. Those are fine in a toy program, but a proper one will need some kind of configuration, so make sure that you use proper values from the beginning:

```
main :: IO ()
main = display FullScreen white . scale width height . pictures $ [
        color blue $ graph f (l, r, b, t) 0.001,
        color black $ Line [(origin, b), (origin, t)],
        color black $ Line [(l, origin), (r, origin)]
    ]
    where
        f :: Float -> Float
        f x = 1 / (x - 1)

        -- easy configurable:
        (l, r, b, t) = (-10, 10, -10, 10)
        width  = 20
        height = 20
        origin =  0
```

That way you can also exchange the values with proper command line interpretation

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    (l, r, b, t) <- getDimensions
    let width = r - l
    let height = t - b
    let origin = ...
    display FullScreen white . scale width height . pictures $ [
...
```

After all, *no magic numbers* is a good practice in both imperative and functional languages.

Next, I'd introduce `GraphBound` as a type synonym, just to make `graph`'s type signature easier on the eye:

```
-- | Graph boundaries, given in (left, right, bottom, top) order
type GraphBound = (Float, Float, Float, Float)

graph :: (Float -> Float) -> GraphBound -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) dx = pictures $ map Line visible
    ...
```

You might even exchange `GraphBound` with a proper `data` type later which checks does not export its constructor to make sure that you don't end up with `left = 20` and `right = -10`:

```
makeGraph :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe GraphBound
```

However, that's an overkill, so let's not focus on that for too long.

## List comprehensions vs. point-free

Now let's get back to your original query. Is it possible to make `graph` more point-free?

Sure:

```
graph :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) = pictures . map Line 
                     . filter (all (\(_,y) -> b <= y && t >= y)) 
                     . (tail >>= flip (zipWith (\x y -> [x, y]))) 
                     . map (\x -> (x, f x)) 
                     . flip (enumFromThenTo l) r . (l+)
```

The point `dx` is completely gone from `graph`. However, the function is now unreadable. We went from a perfectly understandable function to a highly complex one. It gets a lot more readable if we use some helpers, but at that point we're almost back to your original function:

```
graph :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) = pictures . map Line . filter inGraph
                     . segments . points . ranged
   where
     inGraph (_,y) = fall (\(_,y) -> b <= y && t >= y)
     segments ps   = zipWith (\x y -> [x, y]) ps $ tail ps
     ...
```

That's not better than your original version, because **your original version is already very good to begin with**. The only change I could envision is a list comprehension in `visible`, but that's a matter of preference:

```
graph :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) dx = pictures lines
    where
        points = [(x, f x) | x <- [l,l+dx..r]]
        pairs  = zipWith (\x y -> [x,y]) points $ tail points

        lines = [Line segment | segment <- pairs,  all (\(_,y) -> b <= y && t >= y)) segment]
```

But you're the judge on which variant *you* want to use.

## Other remarks

Thank you for using type signatures. Keep in mind that it's uncommon to use them in local bindings (`where`), as the outer function's signature should fix all types already. Inner type signatures can be a hassle if you change your outer type signature later, but they're sometimes necessary.

Answer (score -4):

You should simplify using standard functions and make it more pointfree.

```
import Data.List.Split

graph :: (Float -> Float) -> (Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Float -> Picture
graph f (l, r, b, t) dx = pictures $ map Line
  $ wordsBy (\(_,y) -> b > y || t < y) [(x, f x) | x <- [l,l+dx..r]]
```